# Binding UITableView Title to Model

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

What I try to do is to create a Screen with a TextBox a Button and a TableView. 
I have created the xib, added the elements and created outlets for the button/textbox and the TableView.

I do have a Core-Project which is a PCL and does contain the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CardSets = new ObservableCollection<CardSet>
            {
                new CardSet {Name = "First Entry", Description = "First Entry Description"},
                new CardSet {Name = "Second Entry", Description = "Second Entry Description"}
            };

    }

    private ObservableCollection<CardSet> _sets;
    public ObservableCollection<CardSet> CardSets { 
        get{
            return _sets;}
        set{
            _sets=value;
        }}
```

Actually to test, I immediatly start using to models in my list. 
The model looks as following:

```
public class CardSet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Than I have created the bindings on the .cs-File of my controller:

```
[MvxViewFor(typeof(MainViewModel))]
public partial class TestViewController : MvxViewController
{

    public TestViewController () : base ("TestViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var tableSource = new CardSetTableViewSource(ListViewOutlet);

        this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>()
                         {
            {tableSource, "ItemsSource CardSets; SelectionChangedCommand SearchCardSetsCommand"}
        });

        ListViewOutlet.Source = tableSource;
        ListViewOutlet.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, I bound the ItemsSource of my TableView (which is accidentally called ListViewOutlet.. XD) to my ViewModels CardSets-Property.

The CardSetTableViewSOurce looks as following:

```
public class CardSetTableViewSource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    static readonly NSString CellIdentifier = new NSString("ClientCell");

    public CardSetTableViewSource(UITableView tableView) 
        : base(tableView)
    {
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new CardSetTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, CellIdentifier);
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        }
        return cell;
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And the Cell-Implementation:

```
public class CardSetTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public const string BindingText = @"TitleText Name";

    public static readonly MvxBindingDescription[] BindingDescriptions 
        = new []
    {
        new MvxBindingDescription()
        {
            TargetName = "TitleText",
            SourcePropertyPath = "Name"
        },

    };

    public CardSetTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle cellStyle, NSString cellIdentifier)
        : base(BindingDescriptions, cellStyle, cellIdentifier)
    {
    }
}
```

So and now the problem:
The title is not shown in the list-item. Actually the binding seems to work as the list displays tow items. My binding works on the TextBox and the Button as well. So this is not the problem. Following the debug.Output:

```
2013-04-14 13:03:43.178 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.06 Showing ViewModel MainViewModel
2013-04-14 13:03:43.180 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:   0.06 Navigate requested
2013-04-14 13:03:43.287 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   0.17 Receiving setValue to 
2013-04-14 13:03:43.296 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   0.18 Receiving setValue to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[KaptaCore.Model.CardSet]
2013-04-14 13:03:43.298 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] MvxBind: Diagnostic:   0.18 Receiving setValue to Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand
2013-04-14 13:03:43.306 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] MvxBind: Warning:   0.19 Failed to create target binding for from Name to TitleText
2013-04-14 13:03:43.308 KaptaiOS[91851:c07] MvxBind: Warning:   0.19 Failed to create target binding for from Name to TitleText
```

Any idea what could be wrong?
I run all this stuff out of Xamarin Studio on Mac. I use the latest stable XS. THe MvvmCross build is about 1 week old.

I do already have added a LinkerIncludePlease.cs-File to add a usage of the Name-Property. But as I am running in the simulator in debug mode with linker completly disabled this should not be the problem.

---

Update:

After eading some tutorials and watching some videos I do have a solution:
http://opendix.blogspot.ch/2013/04/binding-viewmodel-to-simple-uitableview.html

Resumed I can say: 
When you only want to show a very simple UITableView, then use "MvxStandardTableViewSource"-class instead of writing an own TableViewSource/cells. 
When you need a custom cell, then watch the video stuart proposed. You have to create a .xib-File for the cell, and implement the binding in the custom-cell implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to create some custom table cells and bind them.

For binding table cells, I recommend you take a look at http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

The code for this demo has been updated to v3 on: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/MonoTouchCellTutorial

Further to this:

- there's a big demo of tables on: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- the Dilbert sample shows the use of 'standard' cell types - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DailyDilbert

Comment: Sorry I can't answer more right now - in the US, srsly busy and jet-lagged

Comment: This is great and actually I guess enough. Guess I misunderstood some stuff about the Cells. I will read some additional stuff and hopefully end in a blog entry about this cell-binding-stuff including my conclusions :-)

Comment: So, read and watched additional stuff, and yes, now it works :-) My conclusion can be read here: http://opendix.blogspot.ch/

Comment: For additional solution-infos -> I'll update the post right now :-)